# JTree: out-of-bounds when firing treeNodesInserted

Tags: java, swing, thread-safety, jtree

I have a `JTree`, Some custom TreeNodes, a Model extendeing DefaultTreeModel and a thread adding nodes to my model.
This can happen at a very high frequency at times.

My nodes are backed by a TreeSet for managing their child nodes: This way the child nodes are always sorted.

My Model has an `add()` method that *tries* to add nodes. If a node with the same identifier already exists, nothing is changed (this is checked against the parent nodes' TreeMap's `KeySet`).

Whenever nodes are added the NodesInserted event is fired.
*Here lies the problem*: Since my tree re-sorts itself whenever nodes are added thanks to the TreeMaps used, the indices passed to the EventListeners may not reflect the position of the nodes added when the listeners handle the NodesInserted event. This is also true for the default listener(s) present responsible for repainting.

Because of this an `out-of-bound exception` is thrown at some point.

How do I make this set-up thread-safe?

Comment: Please be specific at some point: EventListeners may not reflect the position`: which event listener ? Don't give a list just specify the one, you have tried with

Comment: I did not add any EventListener. The `javax.swing.JTree.TreeModelHandler`/`javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTreeUI.Handler` are there by default. The `TreeModelHandler` is the one causing the trouble. I just want to update the UI whenever a node is added.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

```
SortedSet s = Collections.synchronizedSortedSet(new TreeSet(...));
```

Comment: My TreeMaps *are* thread safe.
the Issue is with the TreeModelEvents that store the indices they are given at creation time. The events are then processed by a listener. At The time of processing the indices in the TreeModelEvent are no longer current!